Divisibility (algebraic expressions) - can this be generalised?
Consider the expression $a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}-3abc$.
It is divisible by $(a+b+c)$
Now, consider the expression $a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+d^{3}-3(abc+abd+acd+bcd)$
It is divisible by $(a+b+c+d)$
Can this be generalised to the sum of $n$ cubes where $n\geq 3$?
This post (An interesting question of algebraic manipulation) seems to suggest it is possible, but I'm interested to know if it is possible to find a rule for the quotient, not just prove the division works.

Calculate the quotients in the two cases you've provided. The pattern should be pretty clear.

OK. Thanks Blue - I must have made a mistake because the pattern was not clear to me. I'll look again.

It seems the linked question you provides does not just suggest, it proves it is true, and two of the answers almost explicitly give the quotient as well.
